# Asynchronous Mathjax SVG

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, mathjax

I am using mpld3 to convert Matplotlib plots into D3 web embedable graphics.  I am then using a JS library written on top of MathJax called svg_mathjax2.js (https://github.com/ichuang/svg_mathjax2) to apply Tex conversions.

The error I get is at this line of svg_mathjax2.js:

```
var svgmath = mathjaxdiv.getElementsByClassName('MathJax_SVG')

[0].getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
```

It gives the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
```

Everything works fine the first time I load Mathjax, it converts the text appropriately. However, any additional calls (via AJAX) don't work.

I've posted an issue on the github page, but have not heard back. I'm not sure if this is an issue with svg_mathjax2 or mpld3. Perhaps someone familiar with MathJax can help out?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured this out. It was specific to the svg_mathjax2.js.

I solved it by activating this block of code:

```
if (1) {
        MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End Typeset", function () {
            forEach(items, function (x) {
            });
            // remove the temporary items
            var mathbucket = document.getElementById('mathjax_svg_bucket');
            mathbucket.parentNode.removeChild(mathbucket);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you figured it out, you should share. Come on! Before someone downvotes! ;)